# javascript if condition with multiple ifs

Tags: javascript

I'm running a UI component on every page and on one of the pages, there's an extra functionality linked to it. The UI component has a boolean called `MyValue` and the extra functionality has an object called `ExtraObject` and one of its properties is a boolean called `ExtraBool`.

I want to test if MyValue is true AND if ExtraObject.ExtraBool is false, BUT ONLY if ExtraObject exists. That way, if I'm on the pages that don't have ExtraObject, there's no error.

I tried this:

```
if (MyValue === true && 
    (typeof ExtraObject === undefined || ExtraObject.ExtraBool === false)) {...}
```

How should I rewrite this?

At the moment, I keep getting "ExtraObject is not defined error".

Thanks.

Comment: You don't really need to compare the boolean values to `true` and `false`; just refer to the variable or its logical completment (`!ExtraObject.ExtraBool`)

Comment: @Pointy, although I doubt someone having problems with low-level boolean logic would run into this, it's possible that `MyValue` needs to be `true` but could have alternative values such as `1`, or `'false'`, where it would be necessary to perform a strict equality comparison.

Comment: looks like OP is missing a close paren on the `if` statement...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be:

```
typeof ExtraObject === "undefined"
```

`typeof` returns the type of the expression as a *string*, so you need to compare the name `"undefined"` to the result.

In my opinion, your condition is a bit too explicit. I'd go with something shorter:

```
if (MyValue && !(ExtraObject && ExtraObject.ExtraBool)) {...}
```

If you're communicating with your own GUI code, you can assume that the types are as expected. Type checking in JavaScript is rather cumbersome, so if you know what you're dealing with you can be less explicit. (This doesn't apply to user input though. Never trust user input.)

Comment: Fixed again, so the condition evaluates to `true` if `MyValue` is true and `ExtraObject` is undefined. Had to check your comment on the other answers to verify.

Comment: "if MyValue is true AND if ExtraObject.ExtraBool is false, BUT ONLY if ExtraObject exists"

Comment: Anyway, the solution you provided to test undefined in quotes is good. I prefer long code that's easy to read and then in the end I put it through google closure compiler and get the output optimized.

Comment: Another way would be to just test `ExtraObject === undefined`, but then you might want to locally redefine `undefined` to make sure it's actually `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

The logic is not quite correct:

```
if (MyValue && ExtraObject && !ExtraObject.ExtraBool) { ... }
```

I'm guessing that `null` would be a value `ExtraObject` shouldn't have either; that is, I presume that you r condition is really better stated that it should be a reference to an object.

Thus, the condition as I wrote it will be true when `MyValue` is "truthy", `ExtraObject` is a reference to a real object, and the property `ExtraBool` on that object is "falsy".

Sometimes it's necessary to make explicit comparisons to boolean constants, but in my opinion it's a code smell. (Of course, it can also be dangerous to just check truthiness/falsiness ...)

*edit* If your requirement is that the expression be true when `MyValue` is true and *either* `ExtraObject` is not a reference to an object *or* it's `ExtraBool` property is true, then I'd write that:

```
if (MyValue && (!ExtraObject || !ExtraObject.ExtraBool)) { ... }
```

Which is "better" is a matter of personal preference and experience.

Comment: no, if ExtraObject is undefined and MyValue === true then the condition is met

Comment: Well @frenchie OK but your question is worded incorrectly then.

Comment: where?  "if MyValue is true AND if ExtraObject.ExtraBool is false, BUT ONLY if ExtraObject exists"

Comment: There's no "or" in your wording; I agree however that it's not incorrect, but it is ambiguous, because it's not clear what the "BUT ONLY" part relates to.

Comment: the "BUT ONLY" part relates to ExtraObject: we're testing for ExtraObject.ExtraBool === false ONLY if ExtraObject exists.

Answer (score 1):

Truth table time!

A is `MyValue`*
B is `window.ExtraObject`**
C is `ExtraObject.ExtraBool`

```
A B C | O
------+--
0 0 0 | 0
0 0 1 | 0
0 1 0 | n/a***
0 1 1 | 0
1 0 0 | 1
1 0 1 | n/a***
1 1 0 | 1
1 1 1 | 0
```

What we find with these values is that the simplest equation to produce `O` is:

```
A && !C
```

So your code should be:

```
if (MyValue && !ExtraObject.ExtraBool) {}
```

But of course, you mentioned not wanting to run into issues if `ExtraObject` wasn't defined:

```
var extraBool = window.ExtraObject ? ExtraObject.ExtraBool : false;
if (MyValue && !extraBool) {}
```

An alternative means of writing `extraBool` is:

```
var extraBool = window.ExtraObject && ExtraObject.ExtraBool;
```

You can then inline this:

```
if (MyValue && !(window.ExtraObject && ExtraObject.ExtraBool)) {}
```

An alternative of writing `!(a && b)` is `!a || !b`, which means that:

```
if (MyValue && (!window.ExtraObject || !ExtraObject.ExtraBool)) {}
```

is also correct.

<sub>* it could be `MyValue===true` depending on how strict you need to be

** alternatively `typeof ExtraObject !== 'undefined'`

*** it's not actually possible to have `ExtraObject` be undefined and access `ExtraObject.ExtraBool`</sub>

Comment: ok, thanks! I looked at it and I think your way of doing it is better than what I was doing with the "undefined" test. I upvoted your answer.

Comment: NO, actually your answer doesn't work in "strict mode". So my idea of working with the "undefined" test was actually good!

Comment: @frenchie, oh right, forgot to set it as `window.ExtraObject`, in which case it will work just fine.

Comment: AH YES! Global variables pollute the global scope for a reason. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
if ((MyValue === true) && (typeof ExtraObject === undefined || ExtraObject.ExtraBool === false)) {}
```